# how can I use takeOwnership function?

Tags: openzeppelin-contracts

currently, I'm using openzeppelin.

I can't find takeOwnership function in lately ERC721 interface.

takeOwnership function deprecated?
(I cant' find any document)

so, how can I do that like takeOwnership?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`takeOwnership` was in a [draft of the ERC721 standard](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/721)

> function takeOwnership(uint256 _tokenId)
>   Assigns the ownership of the NFT with ID _tokenId to msg.sender if and only if msg.sender currently has approval (via a previous call to approveTransfer). A successful transfer MUST fire the Transfer event (defined below).

`takeOwnership` is not in the [final ERC721 standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md)

Hence `takeOwnership` is not in the OpenZeppelin implementation.

For information on ERC721 OpenZeppelin see the [OpenZeppelin documentation](https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/tokens#erc721)

The OpenZeppelin tests are a good place to look for how to use and test the contracts
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/master/test/token/ERC721

If you have more questions about OpenZeppelin you can always ask in the [community forum](https://forum.zeppelin.solutions/)